# How to convert Integers to Strings that can be used as column names in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to use two loops to INSERT INTO new_table. The thing is the old_table is like this with strange "year-month" column names:

```
CREATE TABLE old_table
(
    regionname character varying(10),
    "1996-01" integer,
    "1996-02" integer,
    "1996-03" integer,
    ...
    "2014-11" integer,
    "2014-12" integer
)
```

And the empty new_table waiting for data has the schema like this:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
(
  regionname character varying(10),
  year integer,
  month integer,
  value integer
)
```

And I would like to use the parameter y and m in the following function to create column names. For example when y = 1996 and m = 1 in the loops, NEEDTOFILL part should be "1996-01" that can be used as a column name.

```
CREATE FUNCTION insertLoop() RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
  FOR y IN 1996..2014 LOOP
      FOR m IN 1..12 LOOP
          INSERT INTO new_table(regionname, year, month, value)
          (
              SELECT regionname, y AS year, m AS month, **NEEDTOFILL** AS value
              FROM old_table
              WHERE **NEEDTOFILL** IS NOT NULL
          );
      END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

What should be the NEETOFILL? Or is there a way to select the ith column instead of using the actual column name in SQL? Or other ways to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast integer to varchar with :: and concatenate with || like...

```
y::varchar || '-' || m::varchar
```

EDIT
You right. this will generate value not column name
Then you must generate query in to variable then execute query. something like this

```
query = 'INSERT INTO new_table(regionname, year, month, value)
          SELECT regionname, y AS year, m AS month, ' || y::varchar || '-' || m::varchar || ' AS value
          FROM old_table
          WHERE ' || y::varchar || '-' || m::varchar || ' IS NOT NULL';
execute query;
```

Comment: But this way I get "y::varchar || '-' || m::varchar" itself AS value, not the real data stored in "y::varchar || '-' || m::varchar" column. For example I got "1996-05" as value but it is supposed to be the value stored in "1996-05" column

Comment: How to let the complier know that "y::varchar || '-' || m::varchar" is a column name instead of a value?

Comment: I tried old_table.(y::varchar || '-' || m::varchar ) but still doesn't work

Comment: What's the type of query? TEXT?

Comment: Yes. DECLARE query text;